# Standardization/Normalization test data in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, normalization

I'm working in a sklearn homework and I don't understand why one should standardize and normalize the test data with the training mean and sd. How can I implement this in Python? 
Here is my implementation for the train data:

```
digits = sklearn.datasets.load_digits()
X= digits.data
Y= digits.target
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.3,train_size=0.7)
std_scale = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X_train)
X_train_std = std_scale.transform(X_train)
#X_test_std=??
```

For the train i think it's correct, but for the test?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Why?

Because your classifier/regressor will be trained on those standardizes values. You don't want to use your trained-classifier to predict data which has other statistics.

#### How:

```
std_scale = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X_train)
X_train_std = std_scale.transform(X_train)
X_test_std  = std_scale.transform(X_test)
```

Fitting once, transforming whatever you need to transform. That's the advantage of the class-based [StandardScaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) (which you already had chosen) compared to [scale](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.scale.html#sklearn.preprocessing.scale) which does not hold the needed information needed for applying transformations (based on *these* statistics obtained during *fit*) at a later time.